# How do I go about this code Tax for my form

Tags: excel

I need VBA PAYE code for my form for this information.

| Annual Tax Table | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| FIRST 300,00 | 7% |
| NEXT 300,00 | 11% |
| NEXT 500,00 | 15% |
| NEXT 500,00 | 19% |
| NEXT 1,600,00 | 21% |
| ABOVE 3,200,00 | 24% |

PAYE will be

`IF(Taxable Income<300000,1%*Taxable Income,300000*7%)`

`IF(Taxable Income-300000>=300000, 11%*300000,IF(Taxable Income-300000<0,"-",11%*(Taxable Income-300000)))`

`IF(Taxable Income-600000>=500000, 15%*500000,IF(Taxable Income-600000<0,"-",15%*(Taxable Income-600000)))`

`IF(Taxable Income-1100000>=500000, 19%*500000,IF(Taxable Income-1100000<0,"-",19%*(Taxable Income-1100000)))`

`IF(Taxable Income-1600000>=1600000, 21%*1600000,IF(R5-1600000<0,"-",1600000*(Taxable Income-1600000)))`

`IF(Taxable Income-3200000>0,24%*(Taxable Income-3200000),"-")`

I am new in the excel VBA code as this is complicated to me because of formulas I use.

Comment: Does (eg) the number in "FIRST 300,00" mean 300 (three hundred) or 300000 (three hundred thousand). Former could be because your are using a comma (,) as the decimal separator, latter because this is consistent with your `IF` functions.

Comment: Below is the correct table.Note that the Formular above is according to NIG TAX. IT IS OKAY   Annual Tax Table  Rate
FIRST 300,000  7%
NEXT 300,000 11%
NEXT 500,000  15%
NEXT 500,000  19%
NEXT 1,600,00  21%
ABOVE 3,200,000 24%

Answer (score 0):

The formulas would benefit by replacing the hardcoded values (both the tax band limits and the tax rates) with cell references. The band limits and rates should instead be specified on the worksheet. This way changes to tax rates or band limits can be implemented by simple changes to the worksheet rather than by editing formulas. This makes the process of implementing such changes much less prone to error.

The main challenge is to divide the taxable income into "slices" representing the amount of income in each of the different tax bands.

An appropriate way to define the tax bands is by their upper limits. This is shown in the image below where the limits are shown in range `A2:A6` and the tax rates are shown in range `B2:B7`. The lower limit of a tax band is the value of the upper limit of the preceding band.

[image: simple spreadsheet solution]

The income in the example in the image is 1,200,000 and is in cell `B9`. Range `C2:C7` shows how the income has been sliced into the different tax bands, with the formulas used to calculate these values shown in the next column (range `D2:D7`).

Note that references to cell `B9` in these formula are written as `$B$9`. In Excel terminology a cell reference containing $ signs is referred to as an ***absolute*** reference. A cell reference without $ signs is a ***relative*** reference. Understanding these types of reference and how to use them is a core part of being able to use Excel effectively.

Cell `C3` has been copied to the range `C4:C6`. Copying cell `C3` in this way puts its formula into cells `C4`, `C5` and `C6`. Cell references in the formula inserted into `C4`-`C6` remain unchanged if they are absolute references. However, if they are relative references they are changed so that they maintain the same relative position to the "destination" cells as they did in cell `C3` (the "source" cell of the copy/paste operation).

The image shows the formulas used for cell `C3` (it is showing in the worksheet in cell ´D3´) and for cell `C4` - this is showing in the formula bar.

The two formulas are:
`Cell C3: =IF($B$9<=A2,0,IF($B$9<=A3,$B$9-A2,A3-A2))`
`Cell C4: =IF($B$9<=A3,0,IF($B$9<=A4,$B$9-A3,A4-A3))`

The absolute references of `$B$9` remain unchanged when cell `C3` is copied to `C4`. However, the references to cell `À2` in cell `C3` become references to cell `A3` in the formula for cell `C4`. This is because relative to cell `C3` cell `A2` is two columns left and one row up. When cell `C3` is copied to cell `C4` this relative relationship of two columns left and one column up is preserved. References to `A2` get changed to `A3` in the formula for cell `C4`. (If `C3` had been copied to cell `Z100`, preservation of the relationship would mean that a reference to `A2` in the source cell's formula would become references to `X99` in the destination cell's formula.) In the same way, references to cell `A3` in cell `C3` maintain their relative position (in this case of two columns to the left) and so become references to cell `A4` in the formula for cell `C4`.

Effectively, then, the 6 cells `C2:C7` involve just 3 formulas since, in effect, the same formula is applied to all 4 cells in the range `C3:C6`.

Finally, in Excel, `IF` is a function - it delivers a value. This means the if it delivers a numeric value (as in the case of cells `C2:C7`) it can be multiplied by another numeric value. Multiplying by the tax rates means the "Tax" column  can be written as:

`Cell E2: =B2*IF($B$9<=A2,$B$9,A2)`
`Cell E3: =B3*IF($B$9<=A2,0,IF($B$9<=A3,$B$9-A2,A3-A2))`
`Cell E7: =B7*IF($B$9<=A6,0,$B$9-A6)`

with, as before, cell `E3` copied to the cells in the range `E4:E6`. Doing this  makes the "Slice" column (range `C2:C7`) redundant.

These formulas for `E2:E7` refer only to the income (cell `B9`), the tax bands (cells `A2:A6`) and the tax rates (cells `B2:B7`) and are, effectively, the formulas sought in the OP.